# Meta FAQ page should include more verbiage about downvotes

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, down-votes, faq-update-request

In the interest of being nice to new players...

On the FAQ page **for Meta only**, since it's bit of a different beast than the others, the verbiage talking about downvotes:

> If you post something that's off topic
>   or incorrect, it will be voted down:
>   you lose 2 reputation points.

Should include a quick blurb about getting downvoted for people not agreeing with the question / suggestion / proposal / ...

Something like.

> If you post something that's off
>   topic, incorrect, or that those in the
>   community generally disagree with, it
>   will be voted down: you lose 2
>   reputation points.

**Before you flame me, consider:**  This should help to curb "WTF, why did this get downvoted" comment wars thus reducing the load on the site.

Ok, now you can flame me.

Comment: FLAME!!!!!!

Comment: Why do you assume you will be flamed?

Comment: Call it a hunch :)

Comment: Ok, it's a hunch.

Comment: Something of a tangent, but I *hate* the word verbage.

Comment: I hate vegetables too!

Comment: How about "blurbage"?

Comment: I hate verbage too. Especially when it's made into sauerkraut. ...Wait, what's verbage?

Comment: I hate the word "tangent". Reminds me far too much of "tangerine"

Comment: **Wording**

Comment: It's just *so close* to the correct word "verbiage" that I can't tell if people are purposefully using the slang form or they actually think "verbage" is correct.

Comment: I hate the word "Wording"

Comment: I hate [Something Everyone Loves]!!  I'm so wacky!!

Comment: @gnovice: verbiage, touche.  Fixed.

Comment: @squillman: Kudos! My OCD thanks you.

Comment: I hate ointment.  well, actually just the word ointment... and I hate it in one of those loving kind of ways--it's just such a cute ugly word, and saying it is kind of like oink'ing

Comment: Oink, Oink!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Still woefully inaccurate. Should be:

> If you post something that's off topic, incorrect, or that those in the community generally disagree with, or at least *someone* in the community disagrees with, or just doesn't like your phrasing or is having a bad day, or thinks you're getting uppity, or mis-clicks while trying to capture the permalink... it will be voted down: you lose 2 reputation points.

Comment: That's getting long enough to start making it a list.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15251/meta-faq-page-should-include-more-verbiage-about-downvotes/15255#15255

Answer (score 11):

**List of downvote reasons on Meta:**

- Suggestion is deemed stupid/waste of time/unnecessary
- Response is incorrect
- Just because
- Trying to stir things up
- Off Topic
- Someone Disagrees
- Someone Else Downvoted
- Voter is having a bad day
- Miss-Click
- Helping their post sort to the top
- Put the author in their place
- You don't like a particular user
- Author's Gravatar is ugly/looks like a Vampire
- Someone thinks it's opposite day. (Brad Gilbert)
- Voter's monitor is upside-down (essentially mmyers)
- Put voters rep on a cool number (1337, 666, 42, 10,000)

*`<`Work in progress`>`*

In other words, downvotes in meta are not something to get your undies in a bunch about.

Comment: `...`  Someone thinks it's opposite day. `...`

Answer (score 3):

Nothing will curb the "WTF, why did this get downvoted" comments.

Comment: Ok, granted.  At least, then, we could justifiably holler at people for not RTFM.

Comment: Downvoted to see if I could get a reaction. Failed. Removed downvote. (See, there's another point to add to the description: "or if someone is trying to stir things up a little")

Comment: I have never RTFM here.  No need, the users here are really helpful.