# What are valid reasons of casting a (up/down)vote?

Tags: discussion, voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Meta FAQ page should include more verbiage about downvotes.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15251/meta-faq-page-should-include-more-verbiage-about-downvotes)

Currently it appears there's way too many reasons people cast votes. I raise this because I find some of these reasons questionable. So it would be nice if we can vote on what we consider valid reasons to cast either an up or a downvote.

[**note**] I would like this to be either be poll-type (one reason/answer) or FAQ.

Comment: Well, my question is kinda different.

Answer (score 0):

#### downvote - invalid reason

The bug is too minor (specific to meta).