# Why is the post button disabled after I click it?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined

**Observation**

When asking a question on Stack Overflow, and I click the "Post" button, it is disabled, probably to avoid double posting, but I don't see this technique as very good.

**Reason:**

If on clicking the post, I immediately notice some typo error or tag error or something I must correct, the "Post" button is not re-enabled.

**Suggestion:**

I think it would be nice to re-enable the post button on any change to the input fields, or implement another better double post function.

Comment: Please why was my post down voted?

Comment: Probably one of these reasons - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15251/meta-faq-page-should-include-more-verbiage-about-downvotes/15255#15255

Comment: How slow is your internet connection? I've never even noticed this behavior.

Comment: @Renesis, try saving [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange/59446#59446) ;-)

Comment: the behavior you "want" would be *wrong*.

Answer (score 10):

> or implement another better double post function.

Such a "better function" already exists. For five minutes after you post anything, you can use the "edit" link underneath the post and make changes without those changes actually counting as an edit. In other words, the original version won't show up in the revision history; it'll be as if you submitted the corrected version right off the bat.

(Note that changes in this window do *not* reset the five minute counter, though.)

Answer (score 6):

What's wrong with just editing the post immediately after posting it?

Two things come to mind:

1. We want users to get into the habit of editing posts.  No post is set in stone.  The community should continue to edit in order to foster quality content.  (In fact, as @Popular Demand pointed out, edits soon after the fact are considered part of the original so that quick mistakes can be corrected.)
2. The behavior you're describing doesn't sound like a very good idea on a technical level.  You want to click the button, but then hit Stop in your browser and make some edits and click the button again?  This is a bit of a pain from a web development perspective, and it ends up aggravating both the developers and the users.  Once the post request is sent, it's better to treat it as a full and atomic request, let it get handled, and then continue to use the application as designed.  Trying to short-circuit a post request is messy and can easily result in duplicate posts in many cases.  (After all, the server has already received and handled the first "post a question" request, you're just ignoring the response.  If you send another one, it's another question.)