# Tag Subscriptions: How to Find What Tags People are Subscribing to?

Tags: support, tags, tag-watching

Is there a way to compare tags to see which one has a higher number of people who've added a tag to their "Interesting Tags" list? Often, when asking a question, I want as many eye-balls on it as possible, and hopefully the right ones. But if I use a tag that doesn't have a higher subscription rate, my fear is that it won't get the right people to look at it.

So, for example, of the tags **gdi** and **gdi+**, an answer from either will usually work, but by putting in both tags, I'm now left with just three to further meta the question. If nobody or very few people are subscribing to **gdi**, I'd rather not waste the tag by putting that in also when I could use the other tags to get more of the right eyeballs on the question.

**EDIT**:
This is not a question about looking up any one person's tags - just an aggregate or comparative number or something that will help lead me to a better tag if one exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People's tag preferences are private information, not public information, so there is no way to get this information without asking the individual users. And while people have considered requesting this information be public, it's been [somewhat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15229/include-users-interesting-and-ignored-tags-in-the-data-dump) [unpopular](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54631/make-public-interesting-and-ignored-tags).

Comment: I'm not looking for any individual's Interesting Tags, just an aggregate number, or a comparison against another tag. Or even a wonky system prompt that says "Hey, *gdi* doesn't have a lot of subscriptions, maybe try a different tag?" and then if I type in *gdi+* and don't get that prompt, I'll be fine.

Comment: @Otaku Aggregate information is not currently public either, and consequently comparisons. For a related read, please see devinb's answers to both linked questions.

Comment: That's a good point he makes in bullet #3 in the second link about gaming the system. (in fact, that's why I think all the posts tagged with *C#* are a sham - they're not really about C# as much as they are just to get eyeballs). Maybe the suggestion should just be "have the system help me find the right viewers, however it does it".

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that there's a very strong correlation between [tag popularity](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) and subscription rate.  If I were stuck choosing between two tags that seemed to have the same relevance, I'd just go with the more popular one.